# Eclipse birt pdf report with one page for each group of values

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, charts, birt

My database table (data set) looks like:

[image: Database table]

My goal is to create a pdf report with a multiple pages. I want to have one page (with a chart of the group values) for each group.

> Page 1: red - chart
>
> Page 2: green - chart
>
> Page 3: blue - chart
>
> ...

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. 
I created a list with a group (grouped on "color-group") and inserted the chart in the "List group header". Then i enabled page break always after one group.